# matlab - sprintf not printing in script

Tags: string, matlab, cell, printf

So I have a cell containing several strings, e.g.

```
cell = {'a1', 'b2', 'c3'};

for i = 1:3
    sprintf('%s ', cell{i});
end
```

I was expecting some out put like a1 b2 c3 , but there was nothing.
The funny thing is the sprintf works in the command window (without the semicolon).

Please let me know what got wrong. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The `sprintf` function generates a string.  It doesn't output it.  The reason you see it in the command window is probably because you don't write the semi-colon, and so the result is shown to you.

You can use `fprintf` instead, or `disp`.  Look them both up in the MatLab help.

```
doc fprintf
doc disp
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
fprintf(1, '%s ', cell{i});
```

or

```
s = sprintf('%s ', cell{i});
disp(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the similar problem: use a variable for assignment the output from sprintf replace

```
sprintf('%s ', cell{i});
```

to

```
s=sprintf('%s ', cell{i});
```

Here `s` will hold the value of cell when looped as in your case